# How to obtain the IDX_RATIO filed from an HistoricalDataRequest on Bloomberg

Tags: c#, bloomberg, bloomapi

I'm using the Bloomberg API for C# and I try to obtain the IDX_RATIO field for a security using an HistoricalDataRequest. There is a way to obtain this field or isn't a field available?
Thanks

Comment: Have you asked HELP HELP? What security? I get data for `=BDH("AF217300 Corp","IDX_RATIO",20160101,20160331,"cols=2;rows=65")` in Excel.

Comment: I have a list of securities. The problem is that in c# using the api I can't recieve this field for any securities.

Comment: Can you try for `AF217300 Corp`? Are the securities inflation linked bonds?